# Blazor not receiving signalr created on server side

Tags: .net-core, websocket, signalr, blazor, signalr.client

Following many tutorials, examples, this example below I call on the server side, but the client side does not receive, sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn’t (more doesn’t work than it works)

It was supposed to be very simple, but it's not, any suggest will help me so much!

**Server side**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });

        var connection = @"data source=comandai.database.windows.net;initial catalog=HojeTaPago;persist security info=True;user id=Comandai;password=Ck@21112009;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
        services.AddDbContext<ComandaiContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        services.AddSignalR(options => options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "HojeTaPago API", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("basic", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "basic",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Basic Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                      new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "basic"
                            }
                        },
                        new string[] {}
                }
            });
        });

        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        }));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "HojeTaPago API V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<NovoPedidoHub>("/novopedidohub");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**Where im using the signalr**

```
await _novoPedidoContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("NovoPedido", ListaComandaItem);
```

[image: NovoPedidoHub]

**Client side - Blazor**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
        services.AddBootstrapCss();
        services.AddTransient<HubConnectionBuilder>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

Where i call..

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    DataService dataService = new DataService();
    PedidosParaAceitar = new List<Comanda>(await dataService.BuscarComandasAbertas());

    connection = _hubConnectionBuilder.WithUrl(dataService.servidor + "novopedidohub",
        opt =>
        {
            opt.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
            opt.SkipNegotiation = true;
        }).Build();

    connection.On<List<ComandaItem>>("NovoPedido", async lista =>
    {
        var idEstabelecimento = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<int>("IdEstabelecimento");

        if (lista.FirstOrDefault().Comanda.IdEstabelecimento == idEstabelecimento)
        {
            if (PedidosParaAceitar == null)
                PedidosParaAceitar = new List<Comanda>();

            if (PedidosParaAceitar.Count(x => x.Id == lista.FirstOrDefault().IdComanda) > 0)
                foreach (var comandaitem in lista)
                {
                    PedidosParaAceitar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == lista.FirstOrDefault().IdComanda).ComandaItem.Add(comandaitem);
                }
            else
                PedidosParaAceitar.Add(await dataService.BuscarComandaAberta(lista.FirstOrDefault().IdComanda));

            StateHasChanged();
        }
    });

    await connection.StartAsync();
}
```

[image: Console output]

Comment: Can you try to move the client side code in OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) with firstRender == true ?

Comment: Hmm was just re-reading your code - is the SignalR hub on a different server to the client? If so we need to handle making SignalR calls from the "ui-server" - let me know

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify in the tags if this was client-side (WASM) or server-side Blazor.

Looking at the question I noticed this line in `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

So you're attempting to use SignalR, a *client-side communication library* from the Server. In server-side Blazor **all the C# code runs on the server**. In this respect, SignalR is redundant since it's already being used by Blazor for communicating between the clients and the server.

By a very fortunate coincidence, I actually wrote an app to test this out recently. I created a server-side Blazor app, and wrote this service:

```cs
    public class TalkService
    {
        public TalkService()
        {
            history = new List<string>();
        }

        public Action<string> OnChange { get; set; }


        // inform all users of new message
        public Task SendAsync(string message)
        {
            // add to history
            history.Add(message);
            // ensure only last 10 shown
            if (history.Count > 10) history.RemoveAt(0);
            OnChange.Invoke(message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private readonly List<string> history;

        public IReadOnlyList<string> GetHistory() => history;
    }
```

I then registered it as a **Singleton** on the server (all clients use the same service)
in `Startup.cs` in the `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
    services.AddSingleton<TalkService>();
```

Then rewrote `Index.razor` as follows:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject TalkService service

<p>Talk App started</p>

<p>Send a message: <input type="text"@bind="@message" />
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @onclick="Send"  >Send</button>
    </p>

@foreach (var m in messages)
{
    <p>@m</p>
}
@code {
    string message;

    async Task Send()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
            await service.SendAsync(message);
        message = string.Empty;
    }

    List<string> messages;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // load history
        messages = service.GetHistory().ToList();

        // register for updates
        service.OnChange += ChangeHandler;
    }

    protected void ChangeHandler(string message)
    {
        messages.Add(message);
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

The talk service is a basic "chat" example of course. It's a Singleton so all pages/clients that reference it use the same instance. The service has a simple event `OnChange` that clients (like the Index page) can listen to for changes elsewhere.

SignalR isn't needed for this app since it's already "there" for server-side.

#### Demo App

The demo app also has a background service that generates time messages as well. I've pushed this to GitHub to help as a guide:

https://github.com/conficient/BlazorServerWithSignalR

Comment: I needed a simple communication Client-->Server and Server-->All Clients. Studying the documentation I had the impression that I needed NuGet packages etc. but it was mostly for Clients to Clients. This example clarified much better for me and, as Quango stated, all the libraries are already in Blazor. Thank you.

Comment: @Quango I downloaded your sample from github and it works well. The thing is you can't get the connection id from the underlying SignalR hub or send to specific clients can you? Please let me know if you have a way to do this as I am encountering the same issue with sending messages from the Hub to the clients.

Comment: @o_weisman no, you can't as the SignalR connection belongs to Blazor and it's not yours. However, you can add a unique id to each client and pass that to the service and then you can send to specific clients

Comment: @Quango Could you perhaps show a code snippet of how to do this? Maybe add that to the answer? By the way, any idea why sends through IHubContext do not work for the OP and for me?

Comment: I've never used `IHubContext` so can't help with that. Sorry I can't adapt the sample for a demo as it would take a while to redesign for this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to you and found the problem by adding error handling to the signalR connection. When I did I found out that I had an error in how I handled my messages and the error was just swallowed by the connection.

I'd suggest adding `.ConfigureLogging(x => x.AddApplicationInsights())` when you're createing the connection like this:

```
connection = _hubConnectionBuilder.WithUrl(dataService.servidor + "novopedidohub",
    opt =>
    {
        opt.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
        opt.SkipNegotiation = true;
    })
.ConfigureLogging(x => x.AddApplicationInsights())
.Build();
```